# Validate SMTP port number in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, smtp

How to validate (check) if SMTP port number entered by user is available or not? 
Please provide some links or a guide

Comment: SharePoint has not "Test SMPT connection" functionality. But you could for example "Share" a document or site with a user, they shoud be notified by email

Comment: @RobertLindgren I couldn't get you, What document should I share with user ? will you please explain ?

Comment: To be fair I do not fully understand your question. My suggestion was to configure outgoing SMTP with the address and port you have received. Then you can for example create a site in sharepoint and invite a collegue of yours to the site by using the "Share" button in top right

Comment: @RobertLindgren Actually I am developing Module for SMTP Configuration, and I have to put all details which are requeire to configure SMTP,And there is one field SMTP port having button "Validate". after clicking on button user will get to know whether that port is available for use or not. so is there anything in SP that can I use?

Comment: No not that I'm aware of